# Mongoid update multiple records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have records in sample collection in mongodb like

```
{
    "name": "x",
    "value": 2
},
{
    "name": "y",
    "value": 3
},
{
    "name": "z",
    "value": 4
}
```

I want to update the value field for all records by subtracting the value by 1. What I did is

```
samples = Sample.all
samples.each do |sample|
    sample.update_attributes({value: sample.value - 1})
end
```

and I don't feel it's a good way for doing this.
Is there any other way to do so?

I am using mongoid 4.0 and rails 4.1.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try:

```
samples = Sample.all
samples.each do |sample|
    sample.inc("value" => -1)
end
```